# Can I store raw meat in the fridge after defrosting in the microwave?

Tags: defrosting, raw-meat

I had a frozen package of bacon. I only wanted to use half the bacon, but couldn't separate the frozen bacon strips, so I defrosted the whole package in the microwave. The bacon got quite warm - not fully cooked, but smelling like bacon. I used what I needed and put the rest in the fridge immediately. I'm planning on using the rest of the bacon in a few days. Is that a good idea, or should I just throw it away?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use it in a few days, that will be fine. Issues with food safety come into play largely when food is kept in the danger zone, around 40-140F for an extended time.

The texture of the bacon might not be quite as good since it's kind of like the second time you'll be cooking it.

Answer (score -4):

You didn't say HOW LONG it was "quite warm" nor how warm "quite" is, but assuming you mean it was a room temp for a few hours, it's fine. In a more general way, if it doesn't smell bad, it is probably OK.

Comment: Room temp for a few hours would quite possibly spoil the bacon.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I could have been more clear. I put it in the fridge as soon as I took it out of the microwave. "Quite warm" means not fully cooked, but warm enough to smell like bacon, if that makes sense.